# Samsung Galaxy SGH-i897 with SlimBean won't connect to AT&T

Tags: rom-flashing, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-captivate

Samsung Captivate
AT&T Network
Slim Bean 4.2.2

I was having issues with my phone and decided to try a ROM and give the phone a new life.  I chose the SlimBean Android 4.2.2 ROM and all went pretty well.  I like the interface and speed.  I tried to make a phone call this morning and discovered that it isn't connecting to the AT&T cell network.

Is there a step I missed?

Comment: I found that the APN settings weren't sticking.  I tried it dozens of times but it never would stay.